# PL/SQL error while querying BLOBs. "A query with LOB's require OCI8 mode, but OCI7 mode is used"

Tags: blob, plsqldeveloper, lob

I have a table where there is a column defined as BLOB. When i try to query the table, i am not able to view anything and a message is displayed saying "A query with LOB's require OCI8 mode, but OCI7 mode is used". I have unchecked the box "Force OCi7 mode on OCI8", saved and restarted PL/SQL developer and still the error persists. I am using PL/SQL version 5.1.3.704 and OCI: Version 8.1.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Upgrade to the current version for Oracle.

This version can be downloaded by going to: https://support.quest.com/SUPPORT/index?page=downloads.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So is there no other way apart from upgrade, inorder to view the data?

Comment: @NiharikaUpadhyay Are you in LinkedIn